# Число из строки, содержащей нижнее подчёркивание

Tags: javascript

Можно ли с помощью 1 функции получить из строки, состоящей из цифр и символов нижнего подчёркивания, число?
Есть код, в котором надо вставить недостающие имена функций и оператор.

```
formatNumbers(...nums) {
    return someName(nums.join('_'))['someName'](2 operator 2);
}
```

Моё предположение, что вместо 2-го someName надо подставить toString, а вместо operator'a <<. Суть функции: из массива чисел получить склейку и перевести полученное число в 8-ричную систему счисления.

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: дак зачем вы делаете джойн через `_`, сделайте просто джойн без разделителя `(+nums.join('')).toString(16)`

Comment: или ваша задача тут угадать что дожно быть вместо функции `someName` ключа `somename` и оператора `operator` ?

Comment: Задача заменить someName и operator, остальное изменить нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, зачем я помогаю решить этот тест, но ответ, скорее всего, такой:

```js
function formatNumbers(...nums) {
    return eval(nums.join('_'))['toString'](2 << 2);
}

console.log(formatNumbers(1, 0, 0, '3', '74', 54))
console.log(10037454..toString(8))
```